# Sort operator used for PARTITION BY used too much memory (Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to average score grouping by a week number, so that i can display the average, along with a filtered average in the same graph, however running the below query is returning an error.

> Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Sort operator used for PARTITION BY used too much memory..

```
Select
AVG(table.score) OVER (PARTITION BY cal.weeknum) as AVGScore
FROM 
    (Select CONCAT ((CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM exam.start)AS 
    STRING))," ",(CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK(Monday) FROM meeting.start)AS 
    STRING))) AS WeekNum 
    FROM `dbo.data_source.exam` as 
    exam) as cal,
`dbo.data_source.table` as table
```

Is there any alternative function that utilizes less resources, or another method that mitigates the resource requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the `partition by`.  Your problem is the comma in the `FROM` clause.  You are using standard SQL, so this is a `cross join`.

It is unclear what the right join conditions are.  But you can start by removing the comma and using proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax with the join conditions in the `ON` clause.